# Is it possible in practice to reduce someone's magic resist / armor below 0?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've seen a lot of penetration items but not too much items with reduction. Since you can't penetrate below 0 how often it occurs (and how) that you reduce someone's magic resist / armor below 0? With which champions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to get someone's magic resist/armor below zero with proper items/skills/spells. Like you said magic/armor penetration doesn't do that. Only % magic/ resist/armor reduction and flat magic resist/armor reduction.

---

**`MAGIC RESISTANCE REDUCTION`**

***ITEMS***

- Abyssal Scepter: Unique Aura: Reduces the magic resistance of nearby
  enemy champions by 20. +70 ability power, +45 magic resistance. 2650
  gold.
- Malady: Unique Passive: Your basic attacks reduce enemy magic
  resistance by 4 for 8 seconds. Stacks up to 7 times. +25 ability
  power, 50% attack speed. Unique Passive: Your physical attacks shred
  your target doing 15 + 10% of your ability power as bonus magic
  damage. 2035 gold.

***ABILITIES***

**Flat magic reduction:**

- Amumu's  Cursed Touch passively makes his autoattacks reduce the
  magic resistance of enemies hit by 15 / 25 / 35 for 3 seconds.
- Fiddlesticks's  Dread passively reduces the magic resistance of
  nearby enemies by 10.
- Heimerdinger's  H-28G Evolution Turret, at rank 2 and above, reduces
  armor and magic resistance by 1 per hit for 2 seconds (effect stacks
  up to 50 times).
- Kog'Maw's  Caustic Spittle reduces the magic resistance of the target
  by 5 / 10 / 15 / 20 / 25 for 4 seconds.
- Morgana's  Tormented Soil reduces the magic resistance of all targets
  by 4 / 5 / 6 / 7 / 8 each second for 5 seconds.
- Ryze's  Spell Flux reduces the magic resistance of all targets by 12
  / 15 / 18 / 21 / 24 magic resistance reduction for 5 seconds.
- Soraka's  Starcall reduces the magic resistance of all targets by 8 /
  9 / 10 / 11 / 12 for 8 seconds (effect stacks up to 10 times).

**Percentage magic reduction:**

- Trundle's  Agony steals magic resistance of the target by 15% / 20% /
  25%, this amount is doubled over the next 6 seconds.
- Jayce's  Transform: Mercury Cannon grants his next auto attack to
  reduce the enemy's magic resist by 10% / 15% / 20% / 25% for 5
  seconds.
- Karthus's  Wall of Pain reduces the magic resistance of all targets
  affected by 15% for 5 seconds.
- Kayle's  Holy Fervor allows her autoattacks against enemy champions
  reduces their magic resistance by 3% for 5 seconds (effect stacks up
  to 5 times).
- Nidalee's  Bushwhack reduces the armor and magic resistance of
  enemies that step on the trap by 20% / 25% / 30% / 35% / 40% for 12
  seconds.

***SUMMONER SPELLS***

- Exhaust, when augmented by  Summoner's Wrath, reduces the target's
  magic resistance by 10 for its duration.

---

**`ARMOR REDUCTION`**

***ITEMS***

- The Black Cleaver: Unique passive: Dealing physical damage to an
  enemy champion reduces their Armor by 6.25% for 4 seconds. This
  debuff stacks up to 4 times.+250 health, +50 attack damage, +10%
  Cooldown Reduction. Unique: +10 Armor Penetration. 3000 gold.

***ABILITIES***

**Percentage Reduction:**

- Jarvan IV's  Dragon Strike reduces the armor of all enemies hit by
  10% / 14% / 18% / 22% / 26% for 3 seconds.
- Jayce's  Transform: Mercury Cannon reduces the armor and magic
  resistance of the enemy hit by his first attack after cast, by 10% /
  15% / 20% / 25% for 5 seconds
- Kayle's  Holy Fervor reduces the armor and magic resistance of
  enemies hit by her autoattacks by 3% for 5 seconds. This debuff
  stacks up to 5 times.
- Nidalee's  Bushwhack reduces the armor and magic resistance of
  enemies that step on the trap by 20% / 25% / 30% / 35% / 40% for 12
  seconds.
- Renekton's  Slice and Dice, when empowered by having more than 50
  Fury, Dice will reduce the armor of all enemies hit by 15% / 20% /
  25% / 30% / 35% for 4 seconds.
- Shyvana's  Flame Breath reduces the armor of all targets hit by 15%
  for 4 seconds.
- Trundle's  Agony reduces the armor and magic resistance of his target
  by 15% / 20% / 25% and gains for the same amount. This amount is
  doubled over the next 6 seconds.
- Urgot's  Noxian Corrosive Charge reduced the armor of all enemies hit
  by 12% / 14% / 16% / 18% / 20% for 5 seconds.
- Vi's  Denting Blows reduces the target's armor by 20% for 4 seconds
  after every third consecutive hit.
- Wukong's  Crushing Blow reduces the armor of the target hit by 30%
  for 3 seconds.
- Xin Zhao's  Challenge reduces the armor of targets hit by his basic
  attacks or  Audacious Charge by 15% for 3 seconds. Only one target
  may be challenged at a given time

**Flat Reduction:**

- Corki's  Gatling Gun fires automatically every half second, reducing
  enemies armor with each hit by 2 / 4 / 6 / 8 / 10 for 2 seconds.
- Heimerdinger's  H-28G Evolution Turret, while in ranks 2, 3, 4 and 5,
  the turrets' attacks reduce armor and magic resist by 1 per hit
  stacking up to 50 times.
- Kog'Maw's  Caustic Spittle reduces the target's armor and magic
  resistance by 5 / 10 / 15 / 20 / 25 for 4 seconds.
- Nasus's  Spirit Fire reduces the armor of all enemies in the area by
  20 / 25 / 30 / 35 / 40 for the time they are on it plus 1 second.
- Rammus's  Puncturing Taunt reduces the target's armor by 10 / 15 / 20
  / 25 / 30 for 1 / 1.5 / 2 / 2.5 / 3 seconds.
- Taric's  Shatter reduces the armor of all enemies hit by its
  activation damage by 10 / 15 / 20 / 25 / 30 for 4 seconds.

***SUMMONER SPELLS***

- Exhaust, when augmented by  Summoner's Wrath, reduces the target's
  armor by 10 for its duration.

---

**`SOURCE`**

[LOL WIKI](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/League_of_Legends_Wiki)

---

**`EXAMPLE`**

An easy example that everyone can try out and find out if armor can actually go negative is this:

Heimerdinger's level 1 Armor is 10. So get Corki and get exhaust with the Summoner's Wrath mastery.
Go meet each other at a lane (level 1) and exhaust him and use Gatling Gun on him for 2 seconds and watch his Armor become 10 - 10 - 8 = -8!!

Comment: I know all of those items / skills. The emphasis was on **in practice**.

Comment: Don't separate those info from "Practice". Pick any champion of the above. Get exhaust and buy one of the items in the list and you have a good chance of getting an opponent (usually a squishy one) with negative resistances. In practice..

Comment: @AdamArold Im just not sure if you can achieve this with only one champion. Do the math if u want to find out. But im certain that with 2 champions together it would be fairly easy.

Comment: @AdamArold Actually you can! I added an example in the end of my answer above.

Comment: A better example that you're more likely to see in a real game is [Soraka's Q](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Soraka/Ability_Details#Starcall).

Comment: @Yves Yeah its right there on my list ;) -8 Magic Resist/hit on the first level is pretty strong :)